# Change a function to a numeric value

Tags: r, function

I have a function called in the example `fn_example_1` that needs to change with a parameter that comes from another function (`n`).

It needs to have a fixed part that never changes, and a variable part that gets longer with `n`, as an example:

```
# this is the function that needs to change
fn_example_1 <- function(x, mod) {

  # -- this part is fixed
  mod$a <- x^2 # fixed

  # -- this part can change with n 
  mod$b[5,5, k] <- x + 1 # variable
  mod$b[6, 6, k] <- x + 1 #  variable
  # mod$b[7,7, k] <- x + 1 # if n = 3 ecc..

  # k is an arg from a third function, more on that later..
  mod
}
```

This is what I have in mind, basically a wrapper function that gives back a different version of `fn_example_1` that depens on `n`.

```
fn_wrap_example <- function(fn, n) {
  # something
  # something
  # I've thought about a long if else, of course with a max value for n.
  return(fn)
} 

fn_wrap_example(fn_example_1, n = 2) # call to the wrapper
```

It is crucial that `fn_wrap_example` returns a function, this will be an argument to a third function. As a semplification `n` can have a max value, ie: 20.

The key is that `fn_example_1` is a function that changes with `n`.

Comment: I don't get it, which probably means your example is too simplified. Why can't you make `n` a function parameter and just do something like `mod$b[1:n] <- x + 1`?

Comment: because that part is more complex than that, I'll change it to make it more clear.

Comment: Doesn't change my general opinion that `fn_example_1` should have a parameter `n` unless there is something downstream that prevents this (which doesn't seem to be the case since your wrapper has this parameter).

Comment: the third function doesn't like that compact version, I don't know why but I need to "spell" out each new passage as I showed :( sorry if I can't be more clear.

Comment: Looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I see your point but I don't agree 100%, the first problem that I have is that `fn_example_1` is a function that needs to change, the second is how to change it keeping it's structure.

Comment: Your "first problem" surely is not actually first. You claim to need a function factory but I seriously doubt you actually need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can modify a function in your wrapper:

```
fn_factory <- function(n) {
  fn <- function(x, mod) {

    # -- this part is fixed
    mod$a <- x^2 # fixed

    x #place holder

    # k is an arg from a third function, more on that later..
    mod
  }

  ins <- switch(n,
         "1" = quote(mod$b[5,5, k] <- x + 1),
         "2" = quote(mod$b[6, 6, k] <- x + 1)
         )

  body(fn)[[3]] <- ins

  return(fn)
} 

fn_factory(2)
#function (x, mod) 
#{
#  mod$a <- x^2
#  mod$b[6, 6, k] <- x + 1
#  mod
#}
#<environment: 0x0000000008334eb8>
```

I seriously doubt you need this, but it can of course be done.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a closure.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/closures-in-r-a-useful-abstraction/

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html

Simple example:

```
power <- function(exponent) {
  function(x) {
    x ^ exponent
  }
}

square <- power(2)
square(2)
```

Comment: I'm looking into it, but I don't think this is the solution to my problem. Probably my example isn't clear enough.